why apache virtual host website not working
i need your help guys i tried to create my virtual host i follow this tutorial but still do not working i follow more than one they give my same results
sudo apt install apache2






Hi. Kindly check error log file. Share us the exact error message

You mean html file ? Where can i find the log file I don't have any error message while configuration the error only when I tried to access the server

You can find apache log on /var/log/apache2

Also share result of php -v

i uploaded the file https://file.io/GqGauiUdrvVn

this is the php -v pic https://file.io/uajQBOIMHaRs

You may want to check that IP address in your /etc/hosts file, as it's pointing to an external machine. To connect to your local machine, the address should be 127.0.0.1. It's also a good idea to have a matching IPv6 record as well, so adding a line at the bottom will ensure lookups can complete quickly.

I changed the Ip address in /etc/hosts File it works
